# Response.TransmitFile() throws 'Access to the path {path} is denied' using ASP.NET Development Server

Tags: asp.net, access-denied, response.transmitfile

I'm trying to send a protected PDF file (which cannot be accesed directly via the browser) using Response.TransmitFile() but I'm getting "Access to the path ... is denied". I'm using ASP.NET Development Server so I don't know exactly which is the user account that's being used. Anyway I've set Full control for Everyone but still no luck.

What could be causing this? Maybe is not even related to permissions...

The code I'm using is the following, which I'm not sure if it's ok.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content–Disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(file);
Response.End();
```

Comment: but the file is in the project directory isn´t it?

Comment: your variable "file" refers to a physical path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget it... I had an error in the path (did not exists). I hate paths =P